# query to retrieve changes in multiple columns in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table with the assignments details such as location, org, job, grade etc.
I want to build a query such that changes in the location, org are fetched for all system_person_type = 'EMP' only.

```
per_assignments

Person_id    locat_id    org_id    job_id   grade_id       system_person_type   START_DT           END_DT     
1             Toronto    XYZ        1        GR1             EMP                01-JAN-2019        20-JAN-2019
1             US         XYZ        1         GR1            EMP                21-JAN-2019        31-DEC-4712
2             Chicago    ABC        2         GR1            EX-EMP             01-jul-2017        30-Nov-2017
2             Toronto    XYZ        3         GR2            EMP                01-JAN-2019        03-JUL-2019
2             India      GFH        3         GR2            EMP                04-JUL-2019        08-SEP-2019
2             India      GFH        4         GR2            EMP                09-SEP-2019        31-DEC-4712
```

so in the above example the output should be :

```
person_id old_locat_id  new_locat_id      old_org_id    new_org_id old_start_dt   new_start_dat
1          Toronto         US              -               -        01-jan-2019     21-jan-2019
2          Toronto       India             XYZ            GFH       01-JAN-2019     04-JUL-2019
```

I created the below query But from the below query I am getting old_start_dt> new_start_dt and I am not getting all the changes required,
only 1 column change is retrieving. How can the below query be changed to accomadtae the above requirement ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT paam_change_loc.person_id ,  
                to_char(paam_change1.start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')    AS old_effective_start_dt , 
                to_char(paam_change_loc.start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS new_effective_start_dt ,
                paam_change1.location_id    AS old_loc_value , 
                paam_change_loc.location_id AS new_loc_value 
FROM            per_assignments paam_change_loc, 
                per_assignments paam_change1 
WHERE           paam_change_loc.person_id =paam_change1.person_id 
AND            ( 
                                paam_change_loc.location_id IS NOT NULL 
                AND             paam_change_loc.location_id <> paam_change1.location_id ) 
AND             paam_change_loc.system_person_type = 'EMP' 
AND             paam_change1.system_person_type = 'EMP' 
AND             to_char(to_date(paam_change_loc.start_date),'DD-MM-YYYY') BETWEEN ('05-08-2019') AND             '05-12-2019' 
AND             ( 
                              to_char(to_date(paam_change_loc.start_date)-1,'DD-MM-YYYY') BETWEEN ('05-08-2019') AND             '05-12-2019' )
```

'05-08-2019' and  '05-12-2019' is the transfer dates which will be passed to the query and the dates are to be compared in between these two dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query gives expected result:

```
select person_id, prev_start_dt, start_dt, 
       case loc_new when loc_old then ' - ' else loc_old end loc_old,
       case loc_new when loc_old then ' - ' else loc_new end loc_new,
       case org_new when org_old then ' - ' else org_old end org_old,
       case org_new when org_old then ' - ' else org_new end org_new
  from (
    select person_id, locat_id loc_new, org_id org_new, start_dt, 
               lag(locat_id) over (partition by person_id order by start_dt) loc_old,
               lag(org_id) over (partition by person_id order by start_dt) org_old, 
               lag(start_dt) over (partition by person_id order by start_dt) prev_start_dt, 
               case start_dt when 1 + lag(end_dt) over (partition by person_id order by start_dt) 
                             then 1 end flag
          from per_assignments)
  where flag = 1 and (loc_new <> loc_old or org_new <> org_old)
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a9b9f2eacf32b3c421fd6dee7a29fca6)</sup>**

In the inner query apply filters for system_person_type and dates as needed. At first I used `lag()` three times and also to mark continuous rows, in column flag. Then only flagged rows are shown where location or organization changed.

Comment: This will give an error - ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER because it has a lag function on date

Comment: If You are storing dates as strings, you see how bad practice is this, You cannot operate on them. I would change this column types, if not use `to_date`. If your dates are `date` type, please show your query using [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a9b9f2eacf32b3c421fd6dee7a29fca6) tool.

Comment: ribbons- Extremely sorry. didn't realize my mistake until now. the organization id, location id is number data type. I've made the changes in the link you just shared. The query is giving the same error.

Comment: I wrote the org id and loc id as char to make it more understandable

Comment: the link to my table: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c2de5f4092ef01866cf744192993df6a

Comment: Ah, locations are numbers :) Everything you have to do is `to_char()`. [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a3b74f9c4f8371ad23bbf53dcbe41f67)

Comment: Thanks Ponder ! This helps ! One more question.. the dates in my question that is '05-08-2019' and '05-12-2019' are the parameter dates.. the data has to be checked in between these dates. where  should i add these to give me the most accurate results ?

Comment: Add `where` in the inner query, it filters data at the beginning, which matters if table is big.

Comment: Hi @ponder, notsure if i should ask as a separate question .. ive made a change in the query in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2c56f06210bf9221f61cdd73ab7adf3a

Comment: basically, I have another table per_supervisor which will have the same effective_start_date and end date and person id as per_assignments. I have to identify the manager_id change in this table. I tried changing the query ... but it is giving the same effective_start_date and end_date if i include per_supervisor  partition by in the fiddle query that you had suggested..... can you pls help tweaking the query to accomodate this change ?

Comment: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8a7f814b46fadde45c99f3a89f27cdc0) Two versions: one working only on supervisor table, second joins both tables. This was new question. If You have next please open separate one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about data structure of your db. Considering the sample data as table, you can achieve the expected outptut using `analytical` function:

```
Select person_id, 
       Locat_id as old_locat_id,
       New_locat_id,
       org_id as old_org_id,
       New_org_id,
       Start_date as old_start_date,
       New_start_date
  From
(Select t.*, 
       Lead(org_id) over (partition by person_id order by start_date) as new_org_id,
       Lead(start_date) over (partition by person_id order by start_date) as new_start_date,
       Lead(locat_id) over (partition by person_id order by start_date) as new_locat_id,
  From your_table t where system_person_type = 'EMP')
Where locat_id <> new_locat_id or org_id <> new_org_id;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This query isnt working. It is giving the same ids in the old_org_id and New_org_id columns. Also we have to pass the start_date and end_date. not sure the lead function will help to solve in that case